# How to set VerticalOptions, HorizontalOptions in Code Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

```
<ImageButton
   android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
   android:layout_width="308px"
   android:layout_height="560px"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
   android:id="@+id/imgBtn01" />
```

I want set VerticalOptions, HorizontalOptions in code, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.  Yes, there is no following properties in xamarin android:

```
  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
```

The equivalent attribute in Android is `android:layout_gravity`:

[image]

If you want use several values of property , you can use `|` to seperate them,just like this:

```
 android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
```

**2.** If you want image stretch, you can use this property: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.You can try with `centerInside` if you don't want to crop your image, or `centerCrop` if you want to fill all the space (and cropping your image).

[Here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) is a nice list with examples to understand better all the scaleTypes.

[image]:

Note:

For more details, you can check:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType